# Apache Ignite.NET Decimal magnitude overflow

Tags: c#, .net-core, ignite

I'm trying to make something using Apache Ignite .NET however when I try and do a SUM on a decimal field I get the following error:

`Decimal magnitude overflow (must be less than 96 bits): 112`

The query I am trying to run is very simple.

```
SELECT SUM(MYFIELD) FROM MYTABLE
```

And it is mapped to a C# `decimal` type when inserted. The query runs fine in DBeaver and returns a number that's around 60 billion. It also shows the field as a `DECIMAL` in DBeaver.

If I change the field type in C# to be a `double` I do not get the error anymore and everything seems to work smoothly. However I do not want to go and change all my decimal types to doubles in order to get this working.

I was hoping someone here had encountered this before and knew what might be causing it.

Comment: Does ignite SQL allow you to cast away the excessive scale?  eg `select cast(sum(myfield) as decimal(29,4) from mytable`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I hadn't thought about that. This does work and is a possible workaround. I will end up just doing this if I can't find a way to do it differently.

Comment: At first glance, this limitation is introduced due to Java to.NET platform interoperability. SQL decimal maps to Java BigDecimal that has a slightly different binary representation and doesn't have the original restriction.

Answer (score 1):

I think this query tries to convert precise result of SUM(), which is not representable as .Net's decimal, and it refuses to silently do lossy conversion.

Try using `SELECT ROUND(SUM(MYFIELD), 4) FROM MYTABLE` or something similar.